# I have a recipe for an asparagus/pasta dish with a goat cheese sauce, Can I substitute Feta?

Tags: substitutions, cheese

Even generally speaking can Feta be substituted for Goat Cheese? I'm guessing that since Feta is usually more salty I would have to watch the salt, but any other consequences?

Comment: That sounds amazing!! Can I have the link? :D

Comment: @AtillaNYC: You are a question machine!

Comment: I'm a curious guy  :>)  Great Answers, BTW, you're an answer machine!!

Answer (score 5):

Probably not.

Goat cheese is a creamy cheese that melts well and makes a great sauce. Feta, on the other hand, does not melt. It will soften some, but still remain crumbly and chunky. The flavor is significantly different as well; it's much harsher.

You'd be better off with a *fromage blanc*, but chances are if you can find that in the US you'd be able to get the goat cheese there too. A common and more accessible substitute for goat cheese is cream cheese.

Comment: You are fast, hobodave :)

Comment: I am machine. :)

Comment: Agreed. The substitute for (soft) goat cheese is cream cheese. For an aged goat cheese--something harder--substitute if possible a similar sheeps' milk cheese, and then if not possible a cow milk cheese. Feta is not a substitute for goat. Could be delicious, yes, but bears no resemblance.